# How do I get System.Windows.ShowDialog() to return 'true'?

Tags: .net, wpf, dialog

How do I get `System.Windows.ShowDialog()` to return 'true'?

I am a little new to this.  `System.Windows.ShowDialog`'s return type is `bool`? It is supposed to return `true` when you hit `Submit`, and `false` when you hit `Cancel`.  But I am not sure how to designate which `Button` is the official submit button.

EDIT: 
On a related note, I am curious as to how it can return null.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx

> ShowDialog returns a `Nullable<Boolean>` value that specifies
> whether the activity was accepted or
> canceled. The return value is the
> value of the DialogResult property
> before a window closes (see
> DialogResult).

Basically, you decide by setting the value of the DialogResult, not by hitting a particular button -- you decide what the button does.

Comment: My apologies if this is redundant or too obvious, but you should set the bool? DialogResult  value before you call the Close() method inside the dialog. Failure to do so would result in an InvalidOperationException being thrown, with the Exception.Message property being set to "DialogResult can be set only after Window is created and shown as dialog."

Comment: You'll have to pardon me if I've got this wrong, as it's been years since I did WinForms, but I think, yes, you would set the DialogResult _(for example, inside a Button's OnClick handler, but it could be any mechanism you dream up)_, and then call Close().

Answer (score 26):

In WPF, set the [Button.IsDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx) property to true to specify that a button is the "submit" button for a window. I'm not 100% sure that this will make the window close with a DialogResult of true. If it doesn't, you just need to handle its Click event thusly:

```
this.DialogResult = true;
```

**Edit**

Likewise, you can use the [Button.IsCancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.iscancel.aspx) property to have a button be the "cancel" button for a form.

**Edit 2**

I believe the reason ShowDialog is nullable is that since it's null up until the form is submitted or canceled, you could test for that if you were watching the dialog in a background thread. I haven't tried that, but it seems like a logical reason why they'd introduce a third "unknown" (null) state to the property.

Comment: No, setting IsDefault to true will not cause a button click to close the dialog, however, IsCancel will. Setting the DialogResult will close the dialog. Setting Is Default to true causes the command to be triggered if the user hits the Enter key.

Answer (score 9):

if you set DialogResult to true ShowDialog returns true, if you set DialogResult to false ShowDialog returns false if the dialog is closed without setting DialogResult (the user clicks on the red X in the top right corner) ShowDialog will return null.

Setting IsDefault to true will cause the button to look a little different and pressing enter will "click" this button.

If you set IsCancel to true the pressing esc will "click" this button.

Comment: When clicking on the X, ShowDialog will return false, not null. I believe it only returns null, if something went wrong (if ever).